# How to monitor a process running in background without stopping the execution of other shell scripts

Tags: linux, bash, process, ssh

This might sound duplicate. But i would say the scenario I am facing is not discussed.

I have an application which i need to bring it up during the linux boot up (on my ARM device).
However there are lot of scripts which are invoved in the boot up and in one script i am trying to bring the applciation.

I wanted to run it in the background and keep a monitor whenever it exits i want to call another script. I kept the script code as below

```
# To start the application                                                
echo "Starting...."                                               
appName &                                                         
echo "Application Started"
appPid=$!                                                          
while kill -0 $appPid                                              
do                                                                 
    sleep 1                                                        
done                                                            
wait $appPid                                                    
exitstatus="$?"
```

But what happens is when this is executed. The other scripts which are in the boot up sequence are not loaded and i am not able to give TERM and INT signal from my keyboard

I am new to scripting. I know I made a silly mistake but could not figure out myself.

I also read about trap but i just wanted to know what is the best practice to be followed for the above scenario.

Comment: If you want to wait for it to complete, why are you running it asynchronously?

Comment: Why would you ever need to stop the execution of other scripts in order to monitor any process?

Comment: To be honest, i do not want to wait. I just tried it as i found it in internet. I wanted to initiate the process and look for its exit status and report by calling a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fix your hanging startup:

```
 echo "Starting...."
    (
      appName &
      appPid=$!
      echo "Application Started"

      wait $appPid
      exitstatus="$?"
      # more commands here
    ) &
```

You don't need a "kill -0" loop and "wait", they more or less do the same thing (wait is far more efficient though).
The "( ) &" starts a subshell which runs in the background, so your startup process won't hang.
Due to limitations of "wait" you must start the process and wait for it in the same subshell.

This sort of construction is useful to start/monitor/restart a problematic daemon, likely overkill here, and best not placed directly in a startup script. If all you want to do is run the application once on startup, and run a script/report once at exit, a simpler approach is to just run the processes sequentially:

```
(
  echo "Starting application"
  appName
  exitstatus="$?" 
  # more commands here
) &
```

Comment: Thank you. I learnt something today. The rough code seems to work without any blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Your init script should asynchronously invoke another script. This other script should synchronously invoke the target. When the target exits, do whatever you need to do there.

**init.sh**

```
/bin/daemon.sh < /dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

**daemon.sh**

```
appName
exitstatus=$?
/usr/bin/app-terminated.sh
```

Comment: I tried the same from my caller script as above (Except not using the /dev/null parameter) It still dint work.
callerscript.sh <b>
script1.sh & <b> scirpt2.sh & <br> in the script1.sh i have kept the same code without wait. when i rebooted and during the startup process the application is started but i dint get the control on my console yet and its like I kind of stuck. :(...